# How to post an array of files in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I would like to be able to post multiple files in one form.  I would like to pass these files as an array of files.  For example I would like to do this.

```
<input type="file" name="files[0]" />
<input type="file" name="files[1]" />
<input type="file" name="files[2]" />
```

Then I would like to be able to receive these files as an array in the Controller.  I've tried this.

```
public ActionResult AddPart(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
```

But that doesn't work. I've googled it but all I can find is examples on uploading one file.  Does anyone know how to do this using MVC3 C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to upload not only one file, you need to use `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Client", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
```

And controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPart(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

All other parts is ok.

Comment: Is there something else that I could be missing because what you posted as a solution didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got almost a same case. But that is for nested array of files.

using IEnumerable as an array(**[ ]**) solved my problem. [] s

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPart(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>[] files)
```