# json function not calling controller

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I am inserting data in a database using ajax and jquery. when I click the save button then JSON function not Calling controller. I have also use debug and JSON data return this

```
{"Qt_ID":2,"EnteryDate":"11/10/2018","Purpose":"test","Quot":[{"Srno":"1","PartyName":"Brisk","file":"C:\\fakepath\\aaa.png","IsMature":"true"}],"AddNew":"New"}
```

but not passing to the controller. Anyone tell me where I am wrong and what is the problem in my code. i try a lot off but i don't understand what is the problem . any expert kindly review my code and tell me where i am wrong.

C#

```
 public ActionResult mQuotationInsert(int Qt_ID, string EnteryDate, string Purpose, Quotation[] Quot, string AddNew, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";
            try
            {
                objQuotation.QuotationInsert(Qt_ID, EnteryDate, Purpose, Quot, AddNew, file);
                ModelState.Clear();
                result = "Quotation Inserted Successfully!";
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }



  public int QuotationInsert(int Qt_ID, string EnteryDate, string Purpose, Quotation[] Quot, string AddNew, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                tr = con.BeginTransaction();

                if (AddNew == "New")
                {

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Right('00' + Cast(ISNULL(MAX(Qt_ID),0)+1  as varchar(2)) + '', 2) from QuotationMain", con);
                    cmd.Transaction = tr;
                    Qt_ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationMainInsert", con);
                }
                else
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationMainUpdate", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_ID", Qt_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_ID", 1);

                if (EnteryDate != null)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteryDate", EnteryDate);
                else
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EnteryDate", string.Empty);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", HttpContext.Current.Session["AgentName"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Purpose", Purpose);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



                if(Quot !=null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Quot.Length; i++)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            string ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            string physicalPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + ImageName);
                            file.SaveAs(physicalPath);


                            if (AddNew == "New")
                            {
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISNULL(MAX(Qt_Dt_ID), 0) + 1 from QuotationDetail", con);
                                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                                mQt_Det_ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());


                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationDetailInsert", con);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_Dt_ID", mQt_Det_ID);

                            }

                            else if (AddNew == "Edit")
                            {
                                cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_QuotationDetailUpdate", con);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_Dt_ID", Quot[i].Qt_Dt_ID);
                            }

                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_Dt_ID", mQt_Det_ID);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qt_ID", Qt_ID);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SrNo", Quot[i].Srno);

                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartyName", Quot[i].PartyName);
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsMature",Quot[i].IsMature);

                            if (file != null)
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", ImageName);

                            cmd.Transaction = tr;
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }


                    }
                }



                tr.Commit();
                return i;
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw sqlex;  // read all sql error 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw ex; // General execption

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

jquery

```
function saveQuotation(data) {

            if ($.trim($("#Qt_ID").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#txtNEnteryDate").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#txtNPurpose").val()) == "") return;

            return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/mQuotationInsert",
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        location.reload();
                },
                error: function () {
            alert("Error!")
        }
        });

        }

        //Collect Multiple Order List For Pass To Controller

        $("#saveQuotation").click(function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var QuotationArr = [];
            QuotationArr.length = 0;

            $.each($("#detailsTable tbody tr"), function () {

                QuotationArr.push({
                Srno: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                PartyName: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                file: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                IsMature: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html()


            });
        });

            var data = JSON.stringify({
                Qt_ID: parseInt($("#Qt_ID").val()),
                EnteryDate: $("#txtNEnteryDate").val(),
                Purpose: $("#txtNPurpose").val(),
                Quot: QuotationArr,
                AddNew: $("#AddNew").val()
            });

            $.when(saveQuotation(data)).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="centralModalLGInfoDemo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-notify modal-info" role="document">
                <!--Content-->

                <div class="modal-content" style="width:140%">
                    <!--Header-->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <p class="heading lead">Add New Quotation</p>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!--Body-->
                    <form id="NewQuotationForm">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-row">
                                <div class="col" id="Qt_ID">

                                    <div class="md-form">
                                        @Html.TextBox("Qt_ID", (string)ViewBag.QuotationMaxNo, new { @class = "form-control mr-sm-2 w-5", @id = "Qt_ID", @readonly=true, Required = true })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">

                                    <div class="md-form mr-4">
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnteryDate, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNEnteryDate", Required = true })

                                        <label for="lblEntryDate">Entry Date</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col">

                                    <div class="md-form">

                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Purpose, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtNPurpose", Required = true })

                                        <label for="lblPurpose">Purpose</label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>



                            </div>


                            <!--Detail-->
                            <h5 style="margin-top:10px;color:#ff6347">Quotation Details</h5>
                            <hr />
                            <div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <label for="lblPartyName">Party Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="PartyName" name="PartyName" placeholder="Party Name" class="form-control" ,Required=true />


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <form class="md-form">
                                            <label for="lblPartyName">Image File</label>
                                            <div class="file-field">
                                                <div class="btn btn-outline-success  btn-sm float-left">

                                                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="file-path-wrapper" hidden>
                                                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload your file">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <!-- IsMature-->
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsMature, new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "chkNIsMature" })

                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkNIsMature">Mature</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-offset-4">
                                        <a id="addToList" class="btn btn-primary">Add To List</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <table id="detailsTable" class="table">
                                    <thead style="background-color:#007bff; color:white">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width:2%">SrNo.</th>
                                            <th style="width:40%">Party Name</th>
                                            <th style="width:30%">Image</th>
                                            <th style="width:30%">Mature</th>
                                            <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button id="saveQuotation" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Record</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>



                </div>

                <!--/.Content-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create a model in server side

```
public class DataModel
{
    public int Qt_ID { get; set; }
    public string EnteryDate { get; set; }
    public string Purpose { get; set; }
    public Quotation[] Quot { get; set; }
    public string AddNew { get; set; }
}

public class Quotation
{
    public int Qt_Dt_ID { get; set; }
    public int Srno { get; set; }
    public string PartyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsMature { get; set; }
}
```

**It's probably better to use some validations too.**

Then instead of passing every property individually, use the DataModel class

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult mQuotationInsert([FromBody] DataModel model)
{
    // do the rest
}
```

Note the attributes `[HttpPost]` and `[FromBody]`. These two help the data bind correctly.

#### Uploaded File

You have two options.

1. Handle the uploaded file manually
2. Or create a model binder and put that responsibility on its shoulder

For number 2, [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52258048/5282644)

The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Frombody attributr could not be found . when i write in controller

Comment: It's `FromBody` with capital B

Comment: No still same problem.

Comment: ok. the problem is this :  image: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(), is this correct syntax for image url.

Comment: When i remove this  work fine otherwise show msg in alert error .

Comment: i am talking about this line : file: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),

Comment: image URL passing Null.

Comment: I cannot find out how you put the image there, but if you use `<img />` maybe this works: `$(this).find('td:eq(2) img').attr('src')`

Comment: I am just put file and store on the client side ,  in grid show only image name not preview.

Answer (score 0):

try using [HttpPost] attribute above controller method